# ERRLIMIT exceeded

Tags: teradata

ERRLIMIT exceeded
I am doing INSERT into one table in Teradata database, and I got the following error message:

ERRLIMIT exceeded

It doesn't says where the error is.
Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: Are you doing **BULK** insert? Try to insert **ONE** row [at-a-time] - it may give you more detailed error message.  
AFAIR - "ERRLIMIT exceeded" is telling you that there were **TOO MANY** errors in your transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried to insert 1, 10, 450 rows. And it functions. The problem is when I try to insert the whole 820 rows. And can you tell me what could I do to get a little bit more detailed explanation? From Teradata I get only ERRLIMIT Exceeded error, and that´s it

Comment: I am doing insert from tab separated file into table in Teradata

Comment: "File to DB" **IS** a bulk insert transaction. When the number of errors in that transaction exceeds set limit the DB will no longer be able to provide detailed error info.   If you **DO** have control over the DB settings - try setting error limit higher (it may be set to 1 in your current settings).   If you **DON'T** have control over DB settings try locating the statements in error by increasing and decreasing your batch size (it may take many attempts), or write a script to insert the data one record at-a-time.

Comment: I couldn`t find how to set error limit higher. Could you tell me the command please?

Comment: I tried with ERRLIMIT 25; but doesn't work... i get: "Syntax error: expected something between the beginning of the request and the word 'ERRLIMIT'. "

Comment: How are you inserting rows into your table?  Are you using an SQL `INSERT` statement or are you using a utility (`FASTLOAD`, `MULTILOAD`, or `TPT`)?  And if you are not using a utility, how are you connecting to Teradata (`BTEQ`, `SQL Assistant`, or something else)?

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with special characters.
– Germann Arlington  and Bob Duell, thanks for your support.

I did the following to find a solution:
I uploaded the script to Unix machine. After that I opened the script with the Vi text editor.
From there I could identify suspicious characters. After identification I replaced the characters, and was able to load all rows into the table.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Please update your answer with a little more detail on how you were doing your update, what the problem was, and what you did to fix it.  That will help others who may have the same problem (I know I'd be interested).  Then, "accept" your own answer so it shows up as "answered".  Interesting question.

Comment: Hi Bob! I got the impression that you are very experienced colleague in IT area.
I am having trouble with certain problem, and therefore I'd like to ask you if it is possible to send you a message on e-mail or somewhere else since stackowerflow does not allow sending private messages. Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Well, you can try me at my gmail account (user bd9439), but I don't check it often.  I can't really share my "real" email address.  But why don't you just ask your questions here on SO?  Just take your time; specific questions are easier to answer.  But if you have something especially complex, go ahead and sent me a note.